# How do you make the ListHeaderComponent of a React Native FlatList sticky?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a FlatList that is purposefully wider then the screen width.

The list scrolls vertically to view each row and sits in a horizontal ScrollView to access off-screen items.

The ListHeaderComponent prop is basically an x-axis label I'd like to behave as a "frozen header"; like in a spreadsheet.

How do I make the ListHeaderComponent sticky?

Comment: I usually position absolute the header outside of the scrollview to create the sticky header effect.

Comment: Do you have an example Raymond?  I can't picture how to do it.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You need to set prop to `Flatlist` as `stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}`

**ListHeaderComponent**: This prop would set the header view at the top of `FlatList`.

**stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}**: This prop would set the `FlatList` 0 index position item as sticky header and as you can see we have already added the header to `FlatList` so the header is now on 0 index position, so it will by default make the header as sticky.

```
<FlatList
  data={ this.state.FlatListItems }
  ItemSeparatorComponent={ this.FlatListItemSeparator}
  renderItem={ ({item}) => (
    <Text
      style={styles.FlatList_Item}
      onPress={this.GetItem.bind(this, item.key)}> {item.key}
      </Text>
  )}
  ListHeaderComponent={this.Render_FlatList_Sticky_header}
  stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
/>
```

Comment: Hi @Albi. I finally got back around to this and your code worked great! Thank you!!

Comment: @ErikGrosskurth yes it doses.

Comment: Why I don't find this attribute in RN documentation?

Comment: @AndreyPatseiko Great question lot of ppl are asking the same.

Comment: @StanislavMayorov, of course, it won't in horizontal, Because it's like that in native iOS and Android.

Comment: How about stick the children component in ListComponentHeader? Thank in advance.

Comment: @Albi how about showing pull to refresh in FlatList under sticky header instead all the way on top of screen which doesn't look good? refer this existing question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63551063/how-to-prevent-a-header-of-flatlist-from-going-down-when-pulling-to-refresh-in-r

Comment: @LakshmanKambam if you want pull to refresh UI to have custom options it's better to create a custom pull to refresh layout, Its simple

Comment: i've already done it many ways according to my use case. but i'm talking about showing pull to refresh in FlatList only to the dynamic list instead all the way on top of listcomponentheader, if you read my comment properly you will know what my question about! there isn't any option given in flatlist to manage where to show refresh control like stickyHeaderIndices by index of children. i hope you understand! @Albi

Comment: @AndreyPatseiko The stickyHeaderIndices prop is a ScrollView prop, so it's listed in the ScrollView docs instead of the FlatList docs.

Comment: Love how this prop isn't even mentioned [on the official docs page](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist).

Comment: @Albi please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75067444/how-to-add-header-sticky-in-existing-flatlist-in-react-native I need a help

Answer (score 13):

`stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}` would solve your problem.

```js
<FlatList
  data={this.state.data}
  renderItem={this.renderItem}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
  stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
/>
```

Besides, `stickyHeaderIndices` can also be an array of the indices we want to stick. You can even set a lot of indices like this:
[FlatList Sticky Header Example](https://web.archive.org/web/20210517223022/https://docs.nativebase.io/docs/examples/FlatListExample.html)

```
<FlatList
  data={this.state.data}
  renderItem={this.renderItem}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
  stickyHeaderIndices={[0, 6, 13]}
/>
```

When you keep scrolling the `FlatList`, `item0` will be sticky, and then be replaced by `item6`, `item13`.

[image]
<sub>(source: [nativebase.io](https://docs.nativebase.io/docs/assets/FlatListSticky.gif))</sub>

You can't find `stickyHeaderIndices` in the RN `FlatList` documentation. But you can find it in the source code. `VirtualizedList` supports it.

[VirtualizedList.js#L964](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/409c276474ffeea7232aa6b1bccd6958394be06f/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js#L964)

Comment: Hi @RY. That's really good info. Thanks. Can you put a small code example in the answer? `stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}` is already posted by Albi. It would be good for people to see exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: @RY please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75067444/how-to-add-header-sticky-in-existing-flatlist-in-react-native