# How to fix first column in horizontal flat list in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am new in react native, I want to implement horizontal `FlatList` with fix first column.

[react native flatlist sticky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44638286/how-do-you-make-the-listheadercomponent-of-a-react-native-flatlist-sticky)
I checked this questions but it's not working in horizontal `FlatList`

```
<FlatList
  data={this.state.data}
  renderItem={({ item }) => renderData(item)}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
  stickyHeaderIndices={[0]} // it's not working 
  horizontal
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this likewise :

```
   <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <renderData item={this.state.data[0]}/>
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.data.filter((item, index) => index != 0)}
      renderItem={({ item }) => renderData(item)}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
      stickyHeaderIndices={[0]} // it's not working 
      horizontal
    />
   </View>
```